# TimeTrigger Azure Function gives No Module Error in Azure Portal but runs well in VSC

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions

I successfully have created an Azure Time Trigger in Visual Studio Code.

I tested it in VSC before uploading onto Azure portal and it ran ok

[image]

When I run it in Azure though, it gives me an error no module named;
[image]

I have gone back to try and install modules in the.venv and the modules exist.

How can I have this resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function on azure cloud will install the modules according to the `requirements.txt`. So when you deploy the function from local to azure portal, the modules which installed on local will not also be installed on azure cloud if you didn't add the modules to `requirements.txt`. You can run the command below to add all of the modules into `requirements.txt` automatically:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

And then run `func azure functionapp publish <funciton app name on azure> --build remote` to deploy the function from local to azure.

Comment: ShenThanks for the prompt reply. Where do I run this requirement in Azure-kudus -SSH? or in VSC Terminal?

Comment: Hi @wwnde You do not need to run `requirements.txt` in azure kudu. You just need to run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` in VSC terminal to add all of the modules into `requirements.txt` and when you deploy the function to azure portal, it will install the modules according to the content of `requirements.txt` automatically.

Comment: @wwnde You can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61975311/how-to-install-python-module-in-azure-function-linux-app/61998041#61998041) which is similar to your problem.

Comment: I did run the requirements.txt it is step 3 in the post I am having issues with. Where do I get that done?

Comment: I mean where do I run `func azure functionapp publish <function app name> --build remote` tried that in the terminal and `The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: @wwnde Ok, please try to deploy the function to azure cloud by the way you used before.

Comment: @wwnde I think the `requirements.txt` is the key, it doesn't matter in which deploy way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224074/discussion-between-wwnde-and-hury-shen).